# MongoDb sort on date field with $match and $project not working

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am not seeing any type of sort on my data when sorting by a "date" field in mongoDb queries.  The "date_recorded" field IS a date field.

I've also tried sorting on a time_stamp field.  The sort order doesn't appear to be working whether it is ascending or descending.

I cannot seem to figure out why it isn't working.  I've tried it in:
- Compass using the Aggregate tab. 
- Robo3t
- VSCode using NodeJs (a schema model query)

The output is always the same.

***Any help to get this working will be greatly appreciated...***

I've been searching Google and trying different things for about two hours now.

**Here is my query:**

```
db.getCollection('inputData').aggregate(
    { $match: { "inputData_userID": { $eq: "user1" } } }
    ,{ $project: { "date": 1 }}
    ,{ $sort: { "date_recorded": -1 }}
    ,function (err, docs) {}
)
```

**This is the output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "0f30df7453b6096da524d3b61ce75eb1",
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "081be472b94804ae597706aa2bc4d9f4",
    "date" : "4/18/2017"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "0005933cda516a4df346bf0807ab6ca4",
    "date" : "5/19/2017"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "3a67cc9a5eb0a9197fa5448773bfec88",
    "date" : "4/14/2017"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "1aefe9e79faaf4d65c6194b162311e08",
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : "3f4c9d65c207d5cf620a00cee062a4c8",
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}
```

**Here is another query:**

```
db.getCollection('inputData').find(
    { "inputData_userID": { $eq: "user1" } } 
    ,{ "_id": 0, "date": 1, "date_recorded": 1 }
    ,{ $sort: { "date_recorded": -1 }}
)
```

**Here is the output result of this query:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "date_recorded" : ISODate("2017-04-13T08:54:24.024Z"),
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "date_recorded" : ISODate("2017-04-18T22:01:20.767Z"),
    "date" : "4/18/2017"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "date_recorded" : ISODate("2017-05-19T00:03:03.081Z"),
    "date" : "5/19/2017"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "date_recorded" : ISODate("2017-04-14T06:12:55.320Z"),
    "date" : "4/14/2017"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "date_recorded" : ISODate("2017-04-13T23:53:22.692Z"),
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}

/* 6 */
{
    "date_recorded" : ISODate("2017-04-13T08:55:38.721Z"),
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of one aggregation pipeline stage provides the input to the next stage, so you need to include `date_recorded` in your `$project` stage so you can sort on it in the `$sort` stage that follows. But you also need to put your stages in an array instead of providing them as separate parameters:

```
db.getCollection('inputData').aggregate([
     { $match: { inputData_userID: "user1" }}
    ,{ $project: { date: 1, date_recorded: 1 }}
    ,{ $sort: { date_recorded: -1 }}]
    ,function (err, docs) { ... }
)
```

Note that I also simplified your `$match` expression as you don't need to use `$eq` here.

Comment: This one did it!  Thanks.  I was getting the data and then just sorting it by timestamp using a custom function in JavaScript:   array.sort(sortJsonByKey("time_stamp")

Comment: btw, what is better?  sorting in mongoDB or sorting in JavaScript/NodeJs?

Comment: Typically best to sort in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Your first query ans is.

```
db.getCollection('inputData').aggregate(
  [{ $match: { "_id": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(objectId) } }
  ,{ $project: { "date": 1 }}
  ,{ $sort: { "date": -1 }}]
  ,function (err, docs) {}
)
```

Comment: Is that in NodeJs or in Robo3t?

Comment: Actually, it's not working in either.  My NodeJs code is error callback first code, and in Robo3t the sort order hasn't changed:
```/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "0f30df7453b6096da524d3b61ce75eb1",
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "081be472b94804ae597706aa2bc4d9f4",
    "date" : "4/18/2017"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "0005933cda516a4df346bf0807ab6ca4",
    "date" : "5/19/2017"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "3a67cc9a5eb0a9197fa5448773bfec88",
    "date" : "4/14/2017"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "1aefe9e79faaf4d65c6194b162311e08",
    "date" : "4/13/2017"
}


```

Comment: are u matching with userId?

Comment: How could I not be matching with userID when it is in the query?  It's weird.  I see the examples online but they're not working for me for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In mongo-shell i dint have any problem in date sorting in aggregate.

- this is data of date field.

  ```
   db.inputData.find().pretty()
  ```

and gives sample data like this...

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26c292fa53037f6b559aa"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-12T18:30:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26cb82fa53037f6b559ab"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-14T18:30:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26cf72fa53037f6b559ac"),
    "date" : ISODate("2017-04-18T18:30:00Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26d2e2fa53037f6b559ad"),
    "date" : ISODate("2018-04-18T18:30:00Z")
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26d722fa53037f6b559ae"), "date" : "4/19/2018" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26db12fa53037f6b559af"), "date" : "4/19/2019" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26dca2fa53037f6b559b0"), "date" : "5/20/2019" }
```

- For this inputData here is aggregate pipeline only for sorting date field.

  ```
  db.inputData.aggregate([{$sort:{date:-1}}])
  ```
- By running above aggregate soring data is..

  ```
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26d2e2fa53037f6b559ad"), "date" : ISODate("2018-04-18T18:30:00Z") }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26cf72fa53037f6b559ac"), "date" : ISODate("2017-04-18T18:30:00Z") }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26cb82fa53037f6b559ab"), "date" : ISODate("2017-04-14T18:30:00Z") }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26c292fa53037f6b559aa"), "date" : ISODate("2017-04-12T18:30:00Z") }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26b2e2fa53037f6b559a9"), "date" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26dca2fa53037f6b559b0"), "date" : "5/20/2019" }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26db12fa53037f6b559af"), "date" : "4/19/2019" }
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5dc26d722fa53037f6b559ae"), "date" : "4/19/2018" }
  ```
- **One important thing,** for date field, if you want to convert it to date from string you have to run this script..

  ```
       db.inputData.find().forEach(function(doc){
             doc.date = new Date(doc.date);
             db.inputData.save(doc);
       })
  ```